# WDVSS & regex validator

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, userfrosting

I am trying to get the following regex to work with Web Data Validation Standard Schema ([WDVSS](https://github.com/userfrosting/wdvss/blob/master/README.md)) and [UserFrosting](http://www.userfrosting.com).

```
<soapenv:Envelope [\s\S.]*?<\/soapenv:Envelope>
```

It works perfectly fine on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) with javascript flavour but [UserFrosting](http://www.userfrosting.com) does not like it, below is the schema used:

```
{
  "soapRequest" : {
    "validators" : {
      "regex" : {
        "regex" : "<soapenv:Envelope [\s\S.]*?<\/soapenv:Envelope>",
        "message" : "This is not a valid SOAP request."
      }
    },
    "sanitizers" : {
      "raw" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

My form contains a single textarea field for content of a SOAP request. With the regex I want to make sure that the content is in fact a SOAP request.

UserFrosting work fine with a very basic regex like the one below...

```
  "regex" : {
    "regex" : "<soapenv:Envelope.*",
    "message" : "This is not a valid SOAP request."
  }
```

... so the issue is likely to be with the **regex**.

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `"regex" : "/<soapenv:Envelope [\s\S.]*?<\/soapenv:Envelope>/",`

Comment: Wiktor, I tried this already.  No luck :(

Comment: But what is the problem? Do you get any error? Or nothing happens?

Comment: Yes, it is causing the following error:
      [Sat Nov 26 16:41:19 2016] [warn] [client 94.7.91.10] mod_fcgid: stderr: #10 /home2/raceday/public_html/index.php(474): Slim\\Slim->run(), referer: ...

Comment: Sorry, no idea since there is no error here, just a warning.

Comment: Try: `"regex" : "<soapenv:Envelope [\\\\s\\\\S.]*?<\\\\/soapenv:Envelope>",`